# Multithreaded objects loading in OpenGL

Tags: multithreading, opengl, glut

I want to create few threads to load objects with textures, but it doesn't work. I've read that  I should create new OpenGL context in each thread, but when I do it, program crashes on it. Is other way to do it?

I use freeGLUT.
These are functions i want to use in threads:

```
glGenBuffers()
glBindBuffer()
glBufferData()
glGenTextures()
glBindTexture()     
glTexImage2D()
glGenerateMipmap()
glTexParameteri()
glTexEnvi()
```

Answer (score 3):

None of those you can call in a different thread. Not unless you create another connected openGL context in the other thread but that is not simple.

What is simpler is creating the object in memory in another thread and then having the main thread dump it in the VBO. after the loading thread signals it has done.

Another option is first creating and allocating the buffer in the main thread and using `glMapBuffer` to get a pointer you can write to (even from another thread) and letting the loading thread store its data in there and signal back when it's done after which the main thread can unmap it.

Comment: So how to create new context in GLUT?
I don't want to rebuild my loading functions.

Comment: GLUT doesn't provide designated context management. It surely performs some when creating window, but not exposing it to API. If you really want to, you could use WGL/GLX/AGL directly, or SDL/glfw/etc.. However, you don't; it will not grant you performance benefits, quite the opposite. Furthermore, very few things could be shared between contexts, and state is clearly not one of them - so your `bind` and `texenv` cannot be done in multiple threads.

Comment: @keltar but buffer object can be shared which is exactly what you need for multithreaded loading.

Comment: @ratchetfreak with e.g. `wglShareLists`? I'm not sure, but anyway having multiple contexts isn't free. What you've written in answer looks best option available.

Comment: Don't do that. Although it will work, shared contexts are an utterly bad idea which will decrease overall performance. Map buffers and pass pointers.